# Deploy SQL Server Database to Hosting Environment

Tags: sql-server, authentication, deployment

I want to deploy my web application including a SQL Server 2008 database from my local machine to my hoster.

So far I used the Windows authentication, is it necessary to switch to username and password when I want to make my application public on the internet?

And if that's the case, what's the best practice to hide that information if they are saved as strings in the `web.config`?

Side note: I use Linq to Entities as Object Mapper and within the code I use
`HttpContext.Current.User` to authenticate the user

Comment: Are you using shared hosting?

Comment: Hy Faisal i use Managed Hosting for my Web-Application

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are not using shared hosting, then you can keep using windows authentication which is more secure than having SQL server user.
2. You should also disable remote connections so that no one can directly access SQL server to make it more secure.
3. For encrypting connection string [check this site](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Encrypting-Connection-String.aspx).